# Hello I’d like to ask if my grammar is correct! We’re having fun last night!

Tags: irrealis-were

I’d like to ask of my grammar is correct!
We’re having fun last night. Isn’t correct?

Comment: Why would it be correct?

Answer (score 2):

It's not correct.

We're = "we are" (present tense), and "last night" shows you need a past tense.

There is no contraction for "we were".

You might see or hear "we're" used for "we were", even by first-language English speakers, but it's not correct.

Comment: So what is the best Answer?

Comment: We were having fun last night. Correct grammar?

Comment: You should add the actual answer to your answer.